# conversations and store it/them

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number, anaphora

Is "store **it**" correct?

> I listen in to their **conversations** and store **it** all up to tell
>   you later.

I expected the example would read as follows:

> I listen in to their **conversations** and store **them** all up to tell
>   you later.

[Cambridge University Press 2013](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/store-sth-up)

Comment: This is very nice question. The pronoun should agree the noun there. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that "store it" here is actually referring to merely 'data' that can be gleaned from the conversations, not that the listener is going to remember each conversation verbatim to recount later.

So, in effect - listen to all the conversations & report [the gossip] to you later.

Just the interesting bits, the distillation of new information, as a body of data.